# laravel-8 getting error message "Packets out of order. Expected 1 received 4." while running stored procedure with "DB:select" on aws rds mysql db

Tags: mysql, laravel, stored-procedures, amazon-rds

In my laravel 8 app I am calling a mysql stored procedure by following code:

```
$query = DB::select("call rule_sets(?, ?)",[(int)$dataset_id, Auth::user()->id]);
$query_result = $query[0];
```

The code snippet works fine in my local environment. However in my production server (aws ec2 instance + aws rds mysql database) it is throwing `QueryException` with error message `packets out of order. Expected 1 received 4. Packet size=7 (SQL: call rule_sets(1, 1))`. Strangely, when I run this stored procedure directly from any database client connecting with the same production database, it works perfectly. I have tried calling the stored procedure through php `pdo` statement but it still gives the same error message. I have also tried increasing packet size manually on `aws rds` but that didn't work.

Can anyone tell me what is the issue here?

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you. Try updating your `config/database.php` file with the following to the options array under mysql.

```
'options'   => [
                PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES => true
            ],
```

Also you can try updating your `my.cnf` file to increase the `max_allowed_packet` size.

```
max_allowed_packet=300M
```